# Overhead of retrieving large entities in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have some entities in the Google App Engine data store which could be quite large (since they have blobs in them, they could have 1MB of data). Let's assume I have an entity class with the following fields (using Python for the example, but the language is irrelevant):

```
class File(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    size = db.IntegerProperty()
    contents = db.BlobProperty()
```

Now when I do a query, I get back an object of type `File`, which presumably means there will be 1MB of data transfer between the database and the web server, and a 1MB Python object will be created. Are these assumptions correct?

If so, if I wanted to display a table of files without retrieving all of their contents, I would make a query such as

```
SELECT * FROM File ORDER BY name ASC
```

and then display a table of the name and size of each file. Am I correct in thinking that this would actually pull the full contents of every file from the datastore into a Python object?

Since GQL doesn't allow an SQL-like "`SELECT (name, size) FROM ...`", I assume there is no way around this, other than creating a separate entity for the actual contents of each file.

```
class FileContents(db.Model):
    contents = db.BlobProperty()

class File(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    size = db.IntegerProperty()
    contents = db.ReferenceProperty(FileContents)
```

Is this normal practice? Is there another solution? Note that I don't want to use the Blobstore service, as that requires billing enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're assumptions are correct and yes you need two models in order to be able to select just the name field.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions.

Comment: You could use the blobstore to store the file instead of the datastore, and use a `db.BlobReferenceProperty`.

Comment: @Nick Johnson As I said in the question: "Note that I don't want to use the Blobstore service, as that requires billing enabled." This fact is actually not made very clear; I did develop a blobstore app which failed when I uploaded it.